# .htaccess and Wordpress rewriting

Tags: wordpress

I currently host a Wordpress site under my main domain at Liquid Web.  Whenever I type in the url, it points correctly, but any time I click on a link, it then displays as mydomain.com/subdomain.  Here is what I currently have:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /badenfirerescue/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /badenfirerescue/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Any pointers?  I'd like for everything to just show as badenfirerescue.com.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you may need to update your Wordpress URL and Site URL in the wordpress dashboard.  This should update all of your links on the website.

If that doesn't work I would look into downloading the "Velvet Blues Update URLs" plugin.  That will go through the database in the wp_options table and replace your old URL with your new one.